# Node - Q library - Q.reject not going into fail block

Tags: node.js, promise, q

My code is like below. When I do `q.reject(new Error("outside test")` it prints "Fail function". But when I do `q.reject(new Error("inside test")` it does not go into the fail function block and prints nothing. Not sure why is this happening and whats the alternative to achieve what I want. Can anybody help here?

```
    var q = require('q');

    function test(a,callback){
      return callback("a");
    }
    function test2(){
      q(undefined)
      .then(function(){
        //return q.reject(new Error("outside test"));
        test("a",function(err){
            console.log("here2");
            return q.reject(new Error("inside test"));
        });
      })
      .fail(function(err){
          console.log("Fail function");
      });
    }

    test2();
```

Comment: Well, you need to `return` from the `then` callback function. Not from anywhere else. What is your actual problem (if you already found a solution)? Do you control the code of `test`?

Answer (score 0):

The return value `q.reject(new Error("inside test"))` is not the return value of `test()`, but of a callback which is passed to `test()`.

Without information about the `test` function I don't know *what* it returns, but according to what you describe, it is not that rejected promise, but something else, or nothing at all (in which case it is `undefined`). If `test` does not return a promise (or thenable), its returned value will be turned into a promise that immediately resolves, and so the `.fail()` callback is not called.